# Deciding when to stop searching for a new type of shell on a beach?

Tags: pr.probability

Suppose I am on the beach looking for shells. I am interested in finding as many different *types* of shell as possible, rather than shells themselves.

Assuming $T_1, T_2, \dots$ are the types of shell $1, 2,$ etc, and $C_i = |\{T_j: j \le i\}|$ is the number of types of shells for shells $1, 2, \dots j$.

How might I model $C_i$ and assuming a suitable model, when should I stop searching because the number of new shells I need to pick up to be likely to find a new types becomes very large. Is there some code to implement this.

Thoughts:

- I think it would make sense to represent the types of shell as some sort of power law. So we have shell types $S_1, S_2\dots$ such that $P(T=S_j) = k r^j$. Is there a more natural distribution for shell types.
- We might have finite set of types $S_1, S_2, \dots S_n$ with a power law distribution. It would be nice to find the $n$ that maximizes the likehood of our observations.
- I think the result for this might like inside https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_theory or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_stopping.

Comment: While I agree with Iosif's answer that it's hard to say when to stop since it's not clear what your stopping criteria really are, I think it's worth noting that this is pretty close to a generalization of the [Coupon Collector's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).

Comment: Don't stop searching; just move to a different part of the beach, which may have a very different shell population.

Answer (score 6):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}\newcommand{\T}{\mathcal T}$There would be no reason for you to ever stop searching unless you would have to incur a cost/penalty with each new observation/trial.

Suppose, for simplicity, that this cost is a real constant $c>0$, for each observation. Let $[k]:=\{1,\dots,k\}$ be the (say finite) set of the types of shells. Let $U\colon[k]\to\R$ be a utility function such that, for each $j\in[k]$, $U(j)$ is the utility of having exactly $j$ types of shells.

Let $T_1,T_2,\dots$ be the types of shells obtained on trials $1,2,\dots$. Assume that the $T_i$'s are iid random variables with values in $[k]$. For $J\subseteq[k]$, let
\begin{equation}
    p_J:=P(T_1\in J). 
\end{equation}
For natural $n$, consider the random subset
\begin{equation}
    \T_n:=\{T_i\colon i\in[n]\} 
\end{equation}
of $[k]$, so that $|\T_n|$ is the number of (distinct) types of shells obtained on trials $1,\dots,n$.

Then our expected gain after $n$ trials is
\begin{equation}
    G_n:=EU(|\T_n|)-cn,
\end{equation}
which is the expected utility obtained on trials $1,\dots,n$ minus the cost of the $n$ trials. We want to stop at a time moment $n$ maximizing the expected gain $G_n$.

Let us explicitly express the expected gain $G_n$ in terms of the distribution of $T_1$, that is, in terms of the probabilities $p_J$. To do so, consider the events
\begin{equation}
    A_J:=\{\T_n=J\},\quad B_J:=\{\T_n\subseteq J\}
\end{equation}
for $J\subseteq[k]$. Then $A_J=B_J\setminus\bigcup_{j\in J}B_{J\setminus\{j\}}$ and hence
\begin{equation}
    P(A_J)=P(B_J)-P\Big(\bigcup_{j\in J}B_{J\setminus\{j\}}\Big). 
\end{equation}
Noting that $P(B_J)=p_J^n$ and expressing $P\Big(\bigcup_{j\in J}B_{J\setminus\{j\}}\Big)$ by the [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#In_probability), we get
\begin{equation}
    P(A_J)=\sum_{r=0}^{|J|} (-1)^{|J|-r}\sum_{R\in\binom Jr} p_R^n,
\end{equation}
where $\binom Jr$ denotes the set of all subsets of $J$ of cardinality $r$.
Next, for $j\in[k]$,
\begin{equation}
    P(|\T_n|=j)=\sum_{J\in\binom{[k]}j}P(A_J). 
\end{equation}
Thus,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    G_n&=-cn+\sum_{j=0}^k U(j)P(|\T_n|=j) \\ 
    &=-cn+\sum_{j=0}^k U(j)\sum_{J\in\binom{[k]}j}\sum_{r=0}^j (-1)^{j-r}\sum_{R\in\binom Jr} p_R^n.  
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

---

Assuming (say) some kind of parametric model for the distribution of $T_1$, one can estimate the probabilities $p_J$ based on a comparatively small sample of shells and then estimate $G_n$ for all $n$. Alternatively, one may be successively updating the estimates of the $p_J$'s with each new trial.

---

Below is the image of a Mathematica notebook with calculations of $G_n$ for $k=10$, $P(T_1=j)\propto0.6^j$ and $U(j)=\ln(2+j)$ for $j\in[k]$, and $c\in\{0.05,0.1,0.2\}$. It appears that the sequence $(G_1,G_2,\dots)$ has an increasing-decreasing pattern, with maximum attained at $n=2$ for $c=0.2$, at $n=3$ for $c=0.1$, and at $n=6$ for $c=0.05$. (Click on the image to magnify it.)

[image]

Comment: Why the downvote? Something wrong with this answer?

Answer (score 4):

1. [The Good-Turing estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good%E2%80%93Turing_frequency_estimation) addresses a very similar problem.

The model is that there is an unknown number of types $n$ and a probability distribution $p \in \Delta_n$. Each time you pick up a new shell, it is sampled independently from $p$. After $m$ samples, you can ask for the "probability" that a new sample will be of a hitherto-unseen type.

2. I agree with the comment that [the coupon collector problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) is highly related. The model is the same as described above, but we are asked to bound the stopping time (number of samples $m$) after which all types have been seen. Usually, we assume $p$ is the uniform distribution. In this case, the expected number of samples turns out to be roughly $n \log n$. Your question has a twist that we don't know $n$, so we have to do a reverse kind of calculation.
3. I would model your problem as above, and I would assume a confidence parameter $\delta$ is given. The problem is to define a stopping rule such that, for any $n$, the probability that there is still an undiscovered type when we stop is at most $\delta$. This would assume the uniform distribution.

I don't think the optimal solution is obvious, but my first thought is related to Good-Turing. I start drawing samples. At any time $t$, suppose I've seen $n_t$ different types so far and there have been $k_t$ samples since I last saw a new type. If there were at least one undiscovered type, then the chance of it coming up would have been at least $1/(n_t+1)$ on each of those trials, so a total chance of $p_t := \left(\frac{n_t}{n_t+1}\right)^{k_t} \leq e^{-k_t / (n_t + 1)}$ of having this many samples without a new observation.

So if we ever see at least $(n_t + 1) \ln(1/\delta)$ samples in a row without a new type (where $n_t$ is the number of types we've seen so far), we should be able to stop and conclude with confidence $1-\delta$ that we've seen all the types.

4. If we don't assume the distribution is uniform, then I think you can probably modify the above to make a stopping rule of the following form: If we stop, then with confidence $1-\delta$, the total probability on unseen types is at most $\epsilon$. What I mean by confidence is that for any $n$, any $p \in \Delta_n$, and any set of types with $p$-mass at most $\epsilon$, the probability that your procedure stops before seeing one of those types is at most $\delta$. In fact, I think the new rule is to stop once we see $\frac{1}{\epsilon} \ln(1/\delta)$ samples in a row with no new types.
5. The problem is not very related to the optimal stopping or search theory problems I have seen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - need to spend an hour with it one evening to get an idea what's going on. Empirically I suspect I might be able to "repeat types" to get something resembling uniform distribution. I.e. type 1.1, type 1.2, type 1.3, type 2, type 3 etc. For the use case I have in mind the distribution is very non-uniform. I might also be more interested in getting, say, 90% of all types, as the long tail types don't necessarily have that much utility.

Comment: @AttRigh sounds good, let me know if something is unclear. If you are able to quantify a utility for finding new types and also a cost/effort for searching, then Iosif's answer will be better suited for your problem.